# No Graphic drivers on my Ubuntu

Tags: graphics

Im planning to switch to Ubuntu,but i cannot find graphic drivers when i ran ubuntu on a live cd.Im using Asus K53SC notebook.where and how should i find Graphic drivers.Please help.Thank you.

These are my graphic drivers:

[image]

In ubuntu ,it shows graphics Unknown.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

In general You have to install drivers, just like in Windows for example. The best way to see if Your hardware works well is to install Ubuntu on external drive (all, boot and the OS) and to play with it for a while. If everything works well, you can switch Your current OS to Ubuntu without any fear. In case of any probloems You just disconnect Your USB HDD from PC and done. You're back to what You've had.